# gcc dump class hierarchy question

Tags: c++, class, gcc

I'm finding it difficult to wrap my head around the output of gcc's -fdump-class-hierarchy output.  Are there any references/tutorials for using the information that pops out for a given complex class (i.e., multiple virtual inheritance, etc.)?  Using c++filt on the output definitely helped but it just led to more questions as well (e.g., calls seemingly being repeated in the vtable, "non-virtual thunks", etc.).  Any advice in getting up to speed so that this can be an effective tool to trouble shooting things like memory layout issues, determining which functions should be called when, etc.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen the new gcc plugin api http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GCC_PluginAPI 
it will allow you to extract information from the compiler as well.

Also there is http://www.gccxml.org/HTML/Index.html the gcc xml interface that allows you to get at the data. This is used for example http://matt.eifelle.com/2009/07/21/using-gccxml-to-automate-c-wrappers-creation/ with a python interface.

I have spent years researching into various problems like these in the introspector project which is in a horrible state, needs many more years of work.